# Does ffmpeg offer an option to prevent the creation of the Info tag in an MP3 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, lame

I have various MP3 files which I need to process.

The processing includes quite a few steps, but one important one is to remove the Info/Xing tag from the file.

I successfully do so by running `lame -t ...`. However, there are times when I want to run `ffmpeg` to do a conversion which will happen after the `lame -t ...` conversion and I see that `ffmpeg` re-insert an Info/Xing tag in the MP3 file.

Is there a command line option I can use so `ffmpeg` does not re-insert the Info/Xing tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-write_xing 0`

See `ffmpeg -h muxer=mp3`

Comment: Excellent! That will simplify things. Personally, I find the `ffmpeg` help hard to navigate. But that's probably because I'm rather lazy... On the other hand, I would have had a hard time to find the `muxer` part in `-h muxer=mp3`. How to access such is not clearly spelled out.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The documentation is a large tome. The `-h type=name` is mentioned on the 8th line of `ffmpeg -h` output, but it is not particularly intuitive.